# SQL sum over partition for preceding period

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following table, which represent Customers for each day:

```
+----------+-----------+
|   Date   | Customers |
+----------+-----------+
| 1/1/2014 |         4 |
| 1/2/2014 |         7 |
| 1/3/2014 |         5 |
| 1/4/2014 |         5 |
| 1/5/2014 |        10 |
| 2/1/2014 |         7 |
| 2/2/2014 |         4 |
| 2/3/2014 |         1 |
| 2/4/2014 |         5 |
+----------+-----------+
```

I would like to add 2 additional columns:

1. Summary of the customers for the current month
2. Summary of the customers for the preceding month

**here's the desired outcome:**

```
+----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------+
|   Date   | Customers | Sum_of_Current_month | Sum_of_Preceding_month |
+----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------+
| 1/1/2014 |         4 |                   31 |                      0 |
| 1/2/2014 |         7 |                   31 |                      0 |
| 1/3/2014 |         5 |                   31 |                      0 |
| 1/4/2014 |         5 |                   31 |                      0 |
| 1/5/2014 |        10 |                   31 |                      0 |
| 2/1/2014 |         7 |                   17 |                     31 |
| 2/2/2014 |         4 |                   17 |                     31 |
| 2/3/2014 |         1 |                   17 |                     31 |
| 2/4/2014 |         5 |                   17 |                     31 |
+----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

I have managed to calculate the 3rd column by a simple sum over partition function:

```
Select 
  Date,
  Customers, 
  Sum(Customers) over (Partition by (Month(Date)||year(Date) Order by 1) as Sum_of_Current_month
From table
```

However, I can't find a way to calculate the Sum_of_preceding_month column.

Appreciate your support.

Asaf

Comment: For that case I'd like to have a 0 value.

Comment: Check out this post. Seems like its the same topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124756/teradata-equivalent-for-lead-and-lag-function-of-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be easier by using `lag()` and an aggregation sub-query.  The ANSI Standard syntax is:

```
Select t.*, tt.sumCustomers, tt.prev_sumCustomers
From table t join
     (select extract(year from date) as yyyy, extract(month from date) as mm,
             sum(Customers) as sumCustomers,
             lag(sum(Customers)) over (order by extract(year from date), extract(month from date)
                                      ) as prev_sumCustomers
      from table t
      group by extract(year from date), extract(month from date)
     ) tt
     on extract(year from date) = tt.yyyy and extract(month from date) = t.mm;
```

In Teradata, this would be written as:

```
Select t.*, tt.sumCustomers, tt.prev_sumCustomers
From table t join
     (select extract(year from date) as yyyy, extract(month from date) as mm,
             sum(Customers) as sumCustomers,
             min(sum(Customers)) over (order by extract(year from date), extract(month from date)
                                       rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_sumCustomers
      from table t
      group by extract(year from date), extract(month from date)
     ) tt
     on extract(year from date) = tt.yyyy and extract(month from date) = t.mm;
```

Comment: I don't believe Teradata has implemented support for LAG yet. I believe it relies on ROWS PRECEDING and ROWS FOLLOWING clauses in the OVER() windowing function to accomplish LEAD and LAG.

Comment: Thank you Gordon and Rob. I beleive Rob is right. Any idea how can this be acheived with "rows preceding" syntax?

Comment: See @dnoeth response below.

Comment: TD14.10 implements  `FIRST_VALUE` & LAST_VALUE`, which are more generic versions on `LEAD`& `LAG`

Answer (score 3):

The previous month is a bit tricky. What's your Teradata release, TD14.10 supports `LAST_VALUE`:

```
SELECT 
   dt,
   customers,
   Sum_of_Current_month,
   -- return the previous sum
   COALESCE(LAST_VALUE(x ignore NULLS) 
            OVER (ORDER BY dt 
                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
           ,0) AS Sum_of_Preceding_month
FROM 
 (
   SELECT 
     dt,
     Customers, 
     SUM(Customers) OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt,'mon')) AS Sum_of_Current_month,
     CASE -- keep the number only for the last day in month
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt,'mon')
                  ORDER BY dt)
          = COUNT(*) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY TRUNC(dt,'mon'))
       THEN Sum_of_Current_month
     END AS x
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT
     [Date],
     [Customers],
     (SELECT SUM(customers) FROM table WHERE MONTH(dte) = MONTH(tbl.dte)),
     ISNULL((SELECT SUM(customers) FROM table WHERE MONTH(dte) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, tbl.dte))), 0)
 FROM table tbl
```

Comment: I don't this this is Teradata syntax.