# Fill down value to specific date by group

Tags: sql, teradata

I am having a bit of toruble with filling down some values in SQL. Here is an example of the way my data is structured.

```
ID  Date    Value  EndDate
A   1/1/17  500    6/1/17
A   2/1/17  489    6/1/17
A   3/1/17  480    6/1/17
A   4/1/17  475    6/1/17
A   5/1/17  460    6/1/17
A   6/1/17  0      6/1/17
A   7/1/17  0      6/1/17
B   4/1/17  784    8/1/17
B   5/1/17  801    8/1/17
B   6/1/17  0      8/1/17
B   7/1/17  0      8/1/17
B   8/1/17  0      8/1/17
B   9/1/17  0      8/1/17
B   10/1/17 0      8/1/17
C   2/1/17  980    7/1/17
C   3/1/17  564    7/1/17
C   4/1/17  647    7/1/17
C   5/1/17  500    7/1/17
C   6/1/17  0      7/1/17
C   7/1/17  0      7/1/17
C   8/1/17  0      7/1/17
```

For each group, I would like to fill down the value column to the point where the Date is equal to EndDate. The desired output would look like this

```
ID  Date    Value  EndDate
A   1/1/17  500    6/1/17
A   2/1/17  489    6/1/17
A   3/1/17  480    6/1/17
A   4/1/17  475    6/1/17
A   5/1/17  460    6/1/17
A   6/1/17  460    6/1/17
A   7/1/17  0      6/1/17
B   4/1/17  784    8/1/17
B   5/1/17  801    8/1/17
B   6/1/17  801    8/1/17
B   7/1/17  801    8/1/17
B   8/1/17  801    8/1/17
B   9/1/17  0      8/1/17
B   10/1/17 0      8/1/17
C   2/1/17  980    7/1/17
C   3/1/17  564    7/1/17
C   4/1/17  647    7/1/17
C   5/1/17  500    7/1/17
C   6/1/17  500    7/1/17
C   7/1/17  500    7/1/17
C   8/1/17  0      7/1/17
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `Case when Date<=EndDate then value else 0 end as value`

Comment: HI xQbert. I specifically need the last non zero value to be filled down when the result set is ordered by  ID and Date. Does this take that ordering into account?

Comment: Oh 1 sec.  I see now we' carry the prior value forward but only if the date is <= end date.  I thought value contained the desired value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a `LAST_VALUE`-based logic like this: *change zeroes to NULL when date <= EndDate and then look for the most recent existing value*

```
Last_Value(CASE
             WHEN Date <= EndDate
             THEN NullIf(Value,0)
             ELSE Value
           END IGNORE NULLS)
Over (PARTITION BY ID
      ORDER BY Date)
```

Comment: Not completely tested yet but at this point it looks all good!

Comment: NullIfZero? :-)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: Nope, because it's proprietary syntax and `NullIf(Value,0)` is shorter than `NullIfZero(Value)` :-)

Comment: Most functions are proprietary ... :-)

Comment: P.s. Good morning :-)

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd use Lag() analytic, but I don't think teradata supports it so..

```
SELECT Id
     , Date
     , Case when Date<=EndDate then Lag(Value) over (order by ID, EndDate)
            else 0 end as value
     , EndDate
FROM Table
```

... so maybe... based on [Teradata equivalent for lead and lag function of oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124756/teradata-equivalent-for-lead-and-lag-function-of-oracle)

```
SELECT Id
     , Date
     , Case when Date<=EndDate then coalesce(MAX(Value) 
            over (Partition by 1 order by ID, EndDate ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING),0)
            else 0 end as value
     , EndDate
FROM Table
```

I've no test bed for teradata so you'll have to let us know if it works. or what error you encounter

Comment: Checking on this now. Thanks!

Comment: the 2nd one may get some false positives due to the coalese but I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle situations when preceding value didn't exist....