# How to implement lag function in teradata.

Tags: sql, teradata, lag

Input :

[image: I have my data as shown in the image below]

Output :

[image]

I want the output as shown in the image below.

In the output image, 4 in 'behind' is evaluated as tot_cnt-tot and the subsequent numbers in 'behind', for eg: 2 is evaluated as lag(behind)-tot & as long as the 'rank' remains same, even 'behind' should remain same.

Can anyone please help me implement this in teradata?

Comment: What if `tot_cnt` has different values in different rows?

Comment: @trincot i will try to check that later, but first i need to use that lag function in this ..

Comment: Maybe I will wait for you to clarify this first before spending time on it :)

Comment: @trincot the tot_cnt is actually the total number of observations

Comment: LAG implements access to the previous row's data, but I don't see how that matches your expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124756/teradata-equivalent-for-lead-and-lag-function-of-oracle#8130515 - Also Teradata 16.x implements a proper LEAD and LAG function for ANSI compliance.

Answer (score 1):

You appears to want :

```
select *, (select count(*) 
           from table t1 
           where t1.rank > t.rank
          ) as behind
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would summarize the data and do:

```
select id, max(tot_cnt), max(tot),
       (max(tot_cnt) -
        sum(max(tot)) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
       ) as diff
from t
group by id;
```

This provides one row per `id`, which makes a lot more sense to me.  If you want the original data rows (which are all duplicates anyway), you can `join` this back to your table.