# How to Generate Prior Quarter amount using Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Can someone suggest on SQL for the below Input , I am looking to generate Current Quarter and Prior Quarter amount in a row

Input

```
Fiscper Quarter_Amount  
2017Q1  7$

2017Q2  8$

2017Q3  5$

2017Q4  3$

2018Q1  10$
```

Output

```
Output  Current Quarter Amount  Prior Quarter Amount    
2017Q1         7$   

2017Q2         8$                7$

2017Q3         5$                8$

2017Q4         3$                5$

2018Q1         10$               3$
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `lag()` :

```
select t.*, lag(Quarter_Amount) over (order by Fiscper) as Prior_Quarter_Amount  
from table t;
```

However, you can also use subquery :

```
select t.*, (select t1.Quarter_Amount
             from table t1
             where t1.Fiscper < t.Fiscper
             order by t1.Fiscper desc 
             limit 1
            ) as Prior_Quarter_Amount
from table t;
```

Comment: LAG is introduced in Teradata 16.x. Prior versions have to use windowed aggregate functions explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124756/teradata-equivalent-for-lead-and-lag-function-of-oracle